# PHP script dies before ftp_get() finishes downloading a file

Tags: php, ftp

I know how to download a file from a server using FTP with PHP.

I have a list of files to download from the ftp to an internal storage.

I use `ftp_get()` to download the list of files,
the first file size is: 126 mb, successfully downloaded to my internal storage.

However the PHP function throws an error 500, and then dies without continuing.

The error I get:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@zzz.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any idea what I should do in order for the function to complete its run successfully?

Comment: Please check the server logs to read the actual error message. Anything else would be just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you exceeded the maximum execution time.

Try to increase it:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: i try this one and... not working, with this solution we dont have handle with all the case the file size is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the timeout then. 180 is in seconds, which is 3 minutes. Try setting it to 600. I.e.: `FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 600 or higher`, depending on how much more time is needed. You probably could even try `FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 0` which I think is NO time limit.

It is already commented for one more question similar to this. Please try this. It should work.